# How to get a project's directory from within T4?

Tags: .net, mono, t4

I've been messing around with T4 support in Mono and noticed a very cumbersome thing. The current directory when running T4 templates is the home directory. I need to be able to read a few files from the current project's directory but I'm at a loss for how to.

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" #>
<#@ output extension="txt" #>

<#=System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() #>
```

yields

```
/home/earlz
```

where I want it to yield something like

```
/home/earlz/MyProject
```

How do I overcome this problem?

Also, I tried the hostspecific and Host.ResolvePath, but I got a NotImplementedException

Answer (score 7):

Ok, think I've figured it out. You just have to actually resolve paths yourself. To get the directory of the template file(which is good enough for me) just use this:

```
<#= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile) #>
```

Comment: And set your template hostspecific's property to true.

Answer (score 1):

I [fixed ResolvePath](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commit/4d024082a78bf6713113654da8cc5969686a0071) after your [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384703/mono-refuses-to-resolve-relative-paths-in-t4-template-includes/3399510#3399510), along with a ton of [other improvements](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commits/master/main/src/addins/TextTemplating/Mono.TextTemplating). The fix should be in MonoDevelop 2.6, though you could try [building from master](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Building_MonoDevelop).

Comment: Ah, there is my problem then. I was confused as to why that wasn't working. I'm still on MonoDevelop 2.4.1 (using Arch Linux) maybe I'll try building it myself to get the most up to date version

Comment: Ah dang flagged the package out of date before realizing 2.6 isn't actually released yet :(  I'll probably end up putting up with everything until 2.6 is released and the packages for Arch Linux are updated.